# Count unique value ignoring Text in range

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vba, countif

```
123
562
My Data
548
K166
You 
1548
123
562
100
My Data
100
```

I want to count unique values by ignoring text in the above shown list.
For this I've tried an array formula, `{=SUM(1/Countif(,,,,))}` but it's not working properly.

Can anyone suggest a formula or even VBA for the task?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*For the benefit of community I would also like to suggest an array formula with differnt approach, "to count unique values by ignoring text in the given data range".*

[image]

```
{=SUM(IF(FREQUENCY(A2:A13,A2:A13)>0,1,0))}
```

**Note,** *finish the formula with Ctrl+Shift+Enter.*

Comment: Write your Concern,, Why down voted since been accepted by OP & got six up votes??

Answer (score 8):

Here's a solution:

[image: Worksheet Screenshot]

Array enter the following formula anywhere:

```dart
{=SUM(IFERROR(1/COUNTIF(D1:D12,IFERROR(--D1:D12,)),))}
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's another solution inspired by Rajesh's own answer:

[image: Worksheet Screenshot]

Enter the following formula anywhere:

```dart
=SUM(--(FREQUENCY(D1:D12,D1:D12)>0))
```

Note that this formula ***doesn't*** have to be array entered.